# What's the difference between a function and a method?

Tags: java, functions, methods

I've heard that methods are more Object-Oriented than functions.  I was wondering if someone could show me an example of a function and a method and explain the differences between methods and functions?

I have taken 3 quarters of Java programming and functions have never been mentioned, I want to know the differences, strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Java doesn't have standalone functions at all. Are you talking about static methods?

Comment: "function" is not a useful differentiation in this context.  An object's `method` is just a special case of "function" attached to an object.  Many languages, like JavaScript, even use the keyword `function` when writing methods.

Comment: It is sort of unclear as to what you desire in an answer. Are you asking about the relative merits between OOP and functional programming (if so, in what context)? At current your question seems quite broad.

Comment: @user2994925, I think you're just lost in terms. The term "function" is used in procedural programming, "method" is used in OOP. It's pointless to look for functions in Java or any other object oriented language.

Comment: A function is a block of code with no state. A closure (function with captured variables) is a function with state and is like an object with exactly one method. An object is like a collection of closures capturing common variables (the object's **state**). So, you use functions when you need no state, and closures or objects when you do need state. Functions can be thought of as stateless methods, and methods as statefull functions. Once you understand this, you can pick the corresponding constructs in your language of choice. In Java you can use static methods to represent functions.

Comment: Voting to leave open.  The answers and a few of the comments do an excellent job at explaining the difference between the two terms as well as when it's appropriate to use each term.

Comment: I agree to @GlenH7 that your question should not be closed for the reason he gave, but I downvoted it because it is so very unclear what you really want to know. Please consider to edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Are The Specific Meanings Of The Terms: Functions, Methods, Procedures, and Subroutines?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/what-are-the-specific-meanings-of-the-terms-functions-methods-procedures-and)

Answer (score 33):

Speaking strictly, a `procedure` is a subroutine that is executed purely for its side effects (like printing something to the screen) and returns no values.  A `function` is a subroutine that always returns the same value given the same inputs and has no side effects.  A `method` is a procedure or function that is associated with a class or object.

The confusing part is when people use these terms, they're not always referring to the pure definitions.  For the sake of convenience and consistency, programming languages don't always make a distinction between functions, procedures, and methods.  They have one or two ways to declare a subroutine, and whether it's technically a function, procedure, or method depends on how the programmer is using it.

In Java, for example, a `procedure` is created by having a `void` return type on a method.  A `function` is a method with a return type and no side effects, like:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

People whose only programming experience is in a language like Java often don't even realize there's a difference, because in Java it usually doesn't matter in a practical sense.  In a java-only context, programmers often refer to *any* subroutine as a `function`, even by those who know the difference, and they mostly go uncorrected except by the very pedantic.

Comment: The only language I've used that made a distinction between procedures and functions is VB

Comment: ... and Pascal/Delphi. Noteworthy detail that Prism/Oxygene uses `method`. BTW, the OPs question was about function/method, not procedure/function. ;-)

Comment: Getter methods returns a value. Aren't they functions ?

Comment: Getter methods aren't usually functions in the pure sense, because they potentially return a different value different times you call them.  Getters of *immutable* objects are functions though.

Comment: While the distinction between [pure] functions and [effectful] procedures is important, I don't see what does it have to do with the distinction of either from methods. You can easily have standalone procedures that return `void` and produce side effects; `stdlib.h` declares a few. You can have immutable objects with all methods being pure, see `java.lang.String` for an example. It's passing of an object instance in a special way that makes a method; semantically things like `stream.write(data)` and `write(stream, data)` may be equivalent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "the very pedantic" should be my honorific.

Comment: I woould actually use different terminology. What you call "function", I would call "pure function". Anything that may have side-effects but still returns a value, I would call "function" and anything with only side effects is, as you state, a "procedure".

Answer (score 5):

There are no functions per se in Java. All you've got is methods. To imitate functions, Java generally uses static methods (as in `java.lang.Math`).

There is a number of object-oriented languages that provide free-standing functions, though: among them Python, Ruby, JavaScript, C++, Object Pascal, and even (yuck) PHP. There's a good reason behind that.

A method is basically a function with one extra parameter (invisible in Java). You refer to it as [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html). That `this` thing allows you to access the object whose method is being called, so you can think that the entire object is always an implicit parameter to a method, additionally to parameters you normally define.

A method makes sense if it makes use of its object: calls other methods and/or accesses data members. For example, a list can have a `getLength()` method that knows how to calculate list's length, e.g. by scanning each member. It obviously uses the implicit `this` object, that is, the list. This is why it needs no explicit parameters.

Else, a function is enough. For instance, to compute a cosine of an angle you only need the angle, and no other state, so `cos(float angle)` could be a function, and only depend on the explicit `angle` parameter.

Another important thing is *method overriding*. (To my ming, this is a dubious practice, but Java uses it very widely.) You declare a certain class (call it `Z`) a *subclass* of another class (call it `A`), and change implementation of *some* of its methods (suppose we overrode method `foo()`).

The subclass works like the base class (it is said to *provide the same interface*) but does it by different means. According to [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), you can declare a variable of type `A`, assign to it an instance of type `Z`, and invoke method `foo()`; what will be invoked is `Z`'s implementation of `foo()`, not `A`'s. That is, the method to call will be looked up at runtime, based on the actual type of the object. This is know as "dynamic method dispatch" or "virtual methods".

What method overriding provides automatically is not easy to directly emulate with functions. (With functions, similar things are usually done with "callbacks" or "higher-order functions").

In certain languages, such as Java and C#, you can define "static methods" that do not receive a `this` parameter. They work exactly like "standalone" functions and use the class as a namespace. Such namespacing may sometimes make sense, when a static method of a class is used to look up  or create new instances of that class.

I hope you now have a better picture.

Comment: It's worth noting that C# lets you *explicitly* declare functions with the `this` parameter outside of the object itself.  This allows for what they call "extension methods", which allow you to transparently add functionality to an existing class.

Comment: @Bobson: yes, partial classes is a very nice feature of C#. Even more explicit approach is seen in Go, where you _cannot_ declare methods within a class, because classes do not exist, there are only structs and interfaces. You declare an explicit "receiver" parameter in every function you want to work as a method.

Comment: Since @Bobson bought up .NET. In VB.NET, there is a clear difference between subroutine and function syntax, although both come under the umbrella of "Methods".

Comment: Getter methods returns a value. Aren't they functions ?

Comment: @user61852: Many methods return values. What makes a method a method is the fact that an implicit object instance is passed to it and is used inside it: in `foo.bar()` that `foo` is also a parameter to `bar()` invocation. Obviously a getter needs the instance to get something from, so it's strictly a method. In certain languages one could make cosine a method, too: imagine something like `(0.71).cos()`.

Comment: You write "A method is basically a function with one extra parameter (invisible in Java). You refer to it as this" <--- what about static methods, have you forgotten about them?

Comment: @barlop: I did! Since the parameter is implicit (invisible), its omission is not visible in the signature. Java lacks "functions proper", that is, standalone functions that are not methods of some class. Static methods and lambdas (in Java 8) are used instead.

Comment: @9000 Well why don't you make you correct/improve your answer  and not exclude static methods in your definition of method.  On what basis do you define a function as having to be outside of any class? Or even that it must be stand alone.   A static method in a class is rather like a function in a library. Even in a procedural language, functions exist in libraries(though often ones automatically imported) and they don't stand completely alone.

Comment: @barlop: It must not. The notion of a function can even be missing from a programming language at all (look at your nearest Turing machine). Standalone functions do exist in many languages, and historically came much earlier than objects (even if we discount their use in mathematics). Using a class as a namespace is not unreasonable, but Java also has packages for namespacing, these could suffice. Improving an answer is a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @9000 I know some pascal, I know how functions were done prior to OOP. And  I know what a language without procedures would look like.I've written QBASIC sometimes not using procedures.  I understand your definition of function, what i'm asking you is where you get it from?  If somebody says the definition of function doesn't mean it can't be in a class. And you say in the old says, it wasn't. That doesn't mean that the definition of function means it can't be in a class.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in Java **there are no `functions`**. All we have are:

1. Object's methods
2. Class methods (the static ones)

Functions, as *standalone* functions, do not exist in Java.

I would like to support my brief and categorical answer, citing Java's Official Web Page

> Software objects are conceptually similar to real-world objects: they too consist of state and related behavior. An object stores its state in fields (variables in some programming languages) **and exposes its behavior through methods (functions in some programming languages)**. Methods operate on an object's internal state and serve as the primary mechanism for object-to-object communication. Hiding internal state and requiring all interaction to be performed through an object's methods is known as data encapsulation — a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.

Here's the link (In case of someone wants to start with Java concepts before to start with the pure language)

[Java Tutorial - What Is an Object?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

I guess we often call *functions* to *methods* indistinctly. In my case is matter of legacy. My firt langauges were C and Visual Basic. I lernt to design algorithm with *flow diagrams* where *processes* (at diagram) were often called (by my teacher) *functions* or *procedures*. So I find myself (quite often) at job, saying *function* instead of *methods*.

When I was starting with Java (10 years ago), my teacher tried to tag *methods* in 2 groups:

**Processors**. Those methods that causes a change to the arguments recived or to the object's attribute (state change). Whether or not returns values (`void`). Or generate a new value in to the system. Whether or not is persisted.

**Consultors** are those that doesn't cause changes to the object (attributes) or class (static attributes)

At that time I found such catalogation really useful at designing time. Overall because these terms were familiar to me because C and V.B.

Some years later, and after so many *bad practices* and countless lines of  "hilarius code", I would not dare to propose such labeling.

In practice, we end up mixing both concepts in methods that does both things. But that is matter of *best practices* (or bad, depends on your dead lines). I always encourage my job mates to be consequent with the functionality of their code and the way they define methods and their names.

This's my humble contribution to the question :-)

Hope It will help.

Comment: What about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html ?

Comment: All of them are classes ... with methods. The concept of Function is modeled into OOP as classes and methods. But there's no functions like we understood when we were programming C or Visual Basic. This is what I tried to said. I don't dare to do long argumentations because my little english :-)

Comment: @laiv java.lang.math is nothing but a namespace containing **functions** disguised as class methods because, well because of OO.....The concept of functions does exist, just by another name: methods. They're the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real differences between methods, functions and procedures, they're all the same beast: a subroutine, a section of a program, often named doing a specific task.

A method is just a function by another name.

Even java has functions: in "a + b" the "+" operator is a function. Even if it goes by another name.

Imagine you would make a new language: JavaBlub, which is a verbatim copy of Java except for one thing: it hasn't got methods, it's got blubzorz. And blubzorz in JavaBlub do the same thing as methods in Java.

Would you take me seriously when I put on a straight face and say: JavaBlub is different from Java because it doesn't use methods?

Comment: I think Andrew's question was not pointing to so "low" level. I think he was asking **in terms of Java**. In terms of Java's block code. As we know Java is a *High-level programming language* what means (among many other things) an strong abstraction from the details of the computer (those you are mentioning). My answer was focusing in such "abstraction". The abstraction that Java does, where *functions* as he's thinking (in comparission with methods) doesn't exist. Of course under all Java's abstraction there's only logic operations, 1 and 0. But it was not the question :-)

Comment: @Laiv I'm not talking about levels of abstraction, just saying that methods and functions are the same thing by another name, one is not an abstraction of the other.

Comment: I'm in agreement with you. Both are the same thing. So to his question `I was wondering if someone could show me an example of a function and a method` you say *both are the same thing* and I say *There're no 2 things to be compared. Just methods* (again, in terms of Java language). We are saying the very same from different points of view. May be I'm not capable to explain it as well as I would like